# Como sincronizar um banco de dados offline com um online?

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, lógica

Tenho dois banco de dados idênticos, sendo um deles offline e outro online.

Em todo campo de uma tabela eu tenho uma coluna chamada `online` com valores 0 (não enviou os dados) ou 1 (já enviou os dados).

Geralmente eu verifico se existem algum campo na minha tabela com a coluna `online` com valor igual 0, e se tiver, envio o registro pro banco online e altero o valor pra 1.

Funciona muito bem assim. A questão maior é se eu tiver duas pessoas usando o sistema.

Como eu posso enviar dados dos dois clientes pro banco online e fazer que cada um dos clientes receba os dados que o outro enviou?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ola.
Se bem entendi...posso dizer que usar o recurso de replicação de banco de dados seja a melhor alternativa, já passei por uma situação semelhante, onde partes dos dados deveriam estar em vários locais diferentes, de modo que usando a arquitetura convencional (Client/Server) iria sobrecarregar a rede...
Todos os bancos já dão o suporte a réplica, pôstgresql, Oracle, sql server.....Tentar fazer isso na base do código é dor de cabeça na certa..... É possível também que seu problema possa ser resolvido usando a  arquitetura Sass...(Usar Web Api por exemplo..Rest full) Deixe o banco de dados trabalhar nisso...os projetistas já se deram a este trabalho... rsrs 
Desculpa não poder lhe ajudar postando código,  mas foi o que pude inferir do contexto.

Abraco.

Comment: usso mysql, tem algum material que você possa me indicar para pesquisa?

Comment: No google está disponivel uma ampla gama de informação, mas considere entrar em contato com um profissional em MySQL para resolver o problema de forma definitiva e profissional. Digo por que é possível que o tempo de aprendizado lhe dê tanta raiva pelas inumeras tentativas e erro que você acabará por jogar fora uma solução e manter-se como está. (Já passei por isso... rsrsr)

Segue alguns materiais:
1 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qQnICp2vP8w
2 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fUrKt-AQYtE
3 - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html